# How to prevent my application from decompilation

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript

If I have my application attached on my web page as swf, anyone can get the url of the swf and download it - decompile it...what can I do to prevent that, or make my application more safe if there are sensive data?

Comment: Is your question about sensitive data only, or also about protecting your source code?

Comment: i guess the both :), i think that save sensitive data is better in the server-side, but for example if I make post requests to some "secret" urls in my application, i don't want to anyone will know that urls, also all the secret keys will be seen...

Comment: For the love of everything that's important to you, don't base your security on URL's being "secret". You don't even need a decompiling tool to see what URL's an application is using - any sniffer (fiddler, wireshark) will show them. Hell, even the browser might show them at the press of F12. And yes, they can see the query strings too.

Comment: Whenever... You came to the right place. Here's my last advice for today: you can encrypt information going through and from the server, if you're going client-server. It's still not as safe as a condom, but it's as safe as you'll ever get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't. Anything that the user sees is already in their machine. You can't keep them from decompiling your application, much in the same way that you can't keep someone from decompiling a DLL in a windows application.

If you wish to keep sensitive data away from the client, you could have a client-server architecture. Serve only what you don't mind being reverse engineered.

Comment: My one thought after reading the question was "You can prevent a user from decompiling your application if you never distribute it in any way.."   but, this answer is probably more relevant; so +1.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't put sensitive data in the client. Keep the sensitive data server side, and let the server do any comparisons to it, returning just a true/false to the client. I don't think there is a safe/secure way for storing and accessing it client side. As when accessing, that moment can be detected and read out.

**edit:** About your source code, a good enough compiler will make the code pretty hard to read after decompiling. But you can't go much further from there, I think.

Comment: Obfuscation is only a minor hindrance to a bored, idle hacker. Don't ever think of it as a form of security.

Comment: @Renan sure it is a form of security. It's just not very effective. When it comes to protecting your actionscript source code, it even is as good as it gets.

Answer (score 0):

Use obfuscators, for one thing.  I haven't tried any personally, but from doing some research on the web, SecureSWF and especially irrFuscator are probably going to be your best bets.  And as some people have already noted, keep sensitive stuff on the server and out of the swf, because you're not going to block people completely from reverse-engineering this stuff.

Comment: Everytime someone associates obfuscation with security, God kills a kitten.

Comment: It's better than nothing, dude.  It is said that locks are for honest people, but that doesn't mean you shouldn't use them.

Comment: Granted. It'll keep 12-year-old script kiddies out. For a while. But still, good point and upvoted (comment).